# STM32F407 USART transmit

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi

Estoy realizando la programacion de un stm32f407 que comunica con una raspberry por usart.

codigo stm32:

```
   while (1)
   {
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, "hola mundo",10 );
    HAL_Delay(200);
   }
```

codigo python en PI:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
baudrate= 115200,
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout=1 
)

while 1:
   x=ser.readline()
   print (x)
```

configuracion stm32:

```
usart_t2 (pines-> pa2,pa3)
   reloj externo 8Mhz
   sysclk 168Mhz
   hclk 168Mhz
```

configuracion pi

```
   uart (pines-> gpio14-gpio15)
```

El problema es que no se lee nada en la pi.

Comment: Edité el formato del código pero es importante que revises si corresponde con el que tienes actualmente.

Comment: Esta bien el codigo, gracias